# Fill in the StringBlank

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I have a string that has blanks marked by a marker; (in this case, an underscore):

```
"f_ath_r".
```

I can execute the following command to get the word.

```
DictionaryLookup["f" ~~ _ ~~ "ath" ~~ _ ~~ "r"]
```

> `{"feather"}`

How do I create and provide this pattern to the `DictionaryLookup` function starting from the given string?

Thanks.

**Edit: Example of a typical use case**

Starting with a phrase or sentence, for instance: "Actions speak louder than words"; and adding blanks to it randomly.

`a_t_o_s _pe_k l_ude_ t_a_ w__ds`

which upon Dictionary look up becomes:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
pattern = StringReplace["f_ath_r", "_" -> Blank[]]
```

> ```
> "f" ~~ _ ~~ "ath" ~~ _ ~~ "r"
> ```

```
DictionaryLookup @ pattern
```

> ```
> {"feather"}
> ```

Generalizing to allow `__` and `___` in the input string:

```
toSPattern = StringReplace[p : Repeated["_", {1, 3}] :> ToExpression[p]];

DictionaryLookup[toSPattern@"f_ath_r"]
```

> ```
> {"feather"}
> ```

```
DictionaryLookup[toSPattern@"f___ath__r"]
```

> ```
> {"father", "feather", "featherier", "forefather", "forgather"}
> ```

Comment: I hit the accept button many times, but it was frozen in disbelief. As soon as it came out of its catatonic state, it turned green. Many thanks.

Comment: @Syed, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.