# Solving wordle efficiently

Tags: dictionary

I use the following code to solve Wordle(https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/).

The variable **f** contains the pattern for the non-existing letters. **Select** function filters the words which must contain the letter in the word. After every try, I change the variable **f** to include the new letters that should not exist and also add more pipelines of the **Select** function to filter the words.

> f = "[^wodnastjuic]"

> DictionaryLookup[RegularExpression[StringJoin[f, "e", f, f, "y"]]] //
> Select[StringContainsQ["r"]] // Select[StringContainsQ["p"]]

There are some minor inconveniences with this code

1. Multiple **Select** pipelines are required for every letter
2. If in a given position a letter is misplaced then using pattern variable **f** is not optimal, since it does not filter the words that contain the misplaced letter at that position. This can be addressed by providing a new pattern for that position.

Given that the UI will be external how to solve this efficiently?

Comment: For some pointers see [255309](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255309/fill-in-the-stringblank)

Comment: Disambiguation: What google thinks of the word [wordle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HiVv.png). Mathematica has its own built-in `WordCloud` function. There used to be a site called "wordle.net" (can't remember exactly) that used to make word-clouds but it does not exist anymore.