# Solving Wordle like puzzles using dictionary lookup

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, dictionary

I will share a simple non-automated code fragment on how to solve Wordle like puzzles using Mathematica by playing against an automated web opponent. Any other insights to improve the algorithm will be appreciated as always.

One wordle per day is not adequate for testing so I discovered [Absurdle](https://qntm.org/files/absurdle/absurdle.html) that systematically presents the path of greatest difficulty as the solution is reached; it enabled me to include a few more insights about initial word selection.

Disclaimer: For entertainment purposes only. I am not associated with any of the puzzle vendors. Improve and distribute as you see fit. Thanks.

Comment: [Related](https://towardsdatascience.com/tips-and-tricks-for-solving-wordle-efficiently-28ab67a52dbf).

Answer (score 2):

The first part of this solution derives from my previous post [Fill in the StringBlank](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255309/fill-in-the-stringblank).

Define a utility function called `unblankify`.

```
Clear[unblankify]
unblankify[w_String, m_String : "_"] := Module[{pattern, s2},
  s2 = StringSplit[w, m -> Blank[]];
  pattern = StringExpression @@ s2; 
  DeleteDuplicates@ToLowerCase@DictionaryLookup[pattern]
  ]
```

It is not necessary to use `DeleteDuplicates` or `ToLowerCase` in this definition, but that does get rid of some proper nouns and acronyms spelled with upper case letters etc.

**Usage**. If there is a letter marked with a green background on the game board, then one can use this fact to limit possibilities. For example:

```
unblankify["ar___"]
```

> {"arbor", "arced", "ardor", "areal", "areas", "arena", "argon", 
> "argot", "argue", "arias", "arise", "armed", "armor", "aroma", 
> "arose", "arras", "array", "arrow", "arsed", "arson", "artsy", 
> "arums"}

Next, I investigated how many 5-letter words constitute the starting set.

```
words5 = unblankify["_____"];
Length@words5
```

> 6529

and the count of characters in the entire set in order to arrive at good initial word guesses.

```
charsFreq = Flatten@(Characters /@ words5) // Counts // Sort
```

> <|"ü" -> 1, "ö" -> 1, "è" -> 1, "ñ" -> 1, "ô" -> 1, "à" -> 1,   "ó" ->
> 2, "ê" -> 2, "-" -> 2, "é" -> 13, "'" -> 27, "q" -> 56,   "j" -> 140,
> "x" -> 140, "z" -> 170, "v" -> 377, "w" -> 534,   "f" -> 561, "k" ->
> 650, "g" -> 756, "b" -> 814, "h" -> 908,   "m" -> 963, "p" -> 966, "y"
> -> 968, "c" -> 1081, "u" -> 1178,   "d" -> 1338, "n" -> 1617, "t" -> 1711, "l" -> 1854, "i" -> 1902,   "o" -> 2087, "r" -> 2165, "a" ->
> 2962, "s" -> 3242, "e" -> 3453|>

If converted to frequencies, these would be closely related to the frequencies of standard 26 characters in the entire dictionary but the numbers will not be the same.

The most used letters can be turned into 5-letter words such as "arose", "until". Notice that these two words contain all the vowels, so a litmus test would be to remove any words that don't have any of these letters and reach an empty set.

After reducing possibilities using the `unblankify` function, it is time to remove words that contain letters marked in black (that are not present in the answer) and include letters that are shown in amber (that are present but not at their correct location yet). Below, I am using the "aroseuntil" as example characters that should not be present from the entire `words5` set.

```
Pick[unblankify["_____"], (ContainsAll[Characters@""]
      [Characters@#] &&
     ContainsNone[Characters@"aroseuntil"]
      [Characters@#]) & /@ unblankify["_____"]
 ]
```

> {"pygmy", "why'd"}

**Playing**

First step: Here "u" is the only vowel after two attempts and characters from the string "arosentil" should be discarded for future guesses.

[image]

The choices reduce to:

> ```
> {"buddy", "buffy", "buggy", "bumph", "bumpy", "chuck", "chuff", \
> "chump", "duchy", "ducky", "duffy", "dummy", "dumpy", "fuggy", \
> "fuzzy", "gummy", "guppy", "hubby", "huffy", "humph", "jumpy", \
> "khufu", "kudzu", "mucky", "muddy", "muggy", "mummy", "muzzy", \
> "pudgy", "puffy", "puppy", "yucky", "yukky", "yummy"}
> ```

Second step: I entered the word "duchy" as there is no point in entering words with two similar letters and it fixes the "u" and "y", so these were added to the `unblankify` portion and the characters from "dch" were added to exclusions.

[image]

Now the possibilities are:

> {"buffy", "buggy", "bumpy", "fuggy", "fuzzy", "gummy", "guppy", 
> "jumpy", "muggy", "mummy", "muzzy", "puffy", "puppy", "yukky", 
> "yummy"}

Try it and it will systematically not let you get to the final answer except through the hardest path. Seven is a common number of attempts before the game engine runs out of possibilities. If the answer is fixed from the start (as in Wordle), then four attempts are often sufficient.

Comment: This is excellent. Wish you would make it a full fledged Wordle helper. :-)

Comment: I am learning as I go and working on it. The step where I have selected `duchy` above can be improved to rule out the maximum number of remaining consonants. Not that it will help with Absurdle as it is actively playing against the solver but it should reduce an attempt or two with Wordle.

Comment: You should consider posting it here: https://community.wolfram.com/ so a wide range of users sees and uses it - maybe even get a Staff Pick.